# CSS image hover pushes other elements in the page?

Tags: html, image, css, hover

When the image grows in hover to `350px` it pushes everything around.

This code is working except that when I hover and the picture grows it pushes the menu or what ever is around downwards.

How can I stop this?

```
#displaycar img
{
    height: 200px;
}
#displaycar img:hover
{

    height: 350px;

}
```

BTW I'm using twitter bootstrap and I have tried `position: absolute;`.
Is there any way to still increase size when hover but don't push nothing don't move nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of #displaycar (the presumed parent div) to 200px and add overflow: visible;

```
#displaycar {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: this works @commodoretimo but what if this parent is a div where i would live a few more images maybe with different ids and sizes, but i wanna keep this effect through all?

Answer (score 0):

I would use z-index on the elements. keep the values equal on the initial layout, but make it a stronger (bring to front) value when hovering

```
#displaycar img:hover
{
    z-index:[stronger value];
    height: 350px;
    position :[relative, absolute, fixed];
}
```

note: to use z-index, you have to use one of the position values

Z-index gives priority to overlapping elements (bring to front / bring to back)

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) is a bit more info on the subject

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but to avoid affecting surrounding content the element itself has to be removed from the flow of the document; this is easiest to achieve using `position: absolute`, though unfortunately this requires using a wrapping element, with `position: relative` (or any other non-`static` `position` value). The wrapping element has to have a width and height defined, which could be done automatically (with JavaScript, or PHP (amongst many other options)).

For example, the HTML:

```
<span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400/" />
</span>
<p><!-- generic dummy content, excised for brevity --></p>
```

And the CSS:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

span img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    /* Vendor-prefixes removed, for brevity */
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
span:hover img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    /* Vendor-prefixes removed, for brevity */
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ndYVS/1/).